# Canvas app in 2gp managed package

Tags: managed-package, package, canvas, canvaslifecyclehandler

I have connected app on my scratch org which is rendering canvas app in aura component.
On my connected (canvas app) im using `CanvasLifecycleHandler` class implementation on connected app settings.

I'm having issues with creating new version of canvas app with connected app , i tried to follow this [SF Documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#sfdx_dev_dev2gp_connected_app). I have 1gp managed with the same namespace as 2gp.  Package have connected app only (without `CanvasLifecycleHandler` , just 'empty' app with client id and client secret

When im trying to create new managed package version , i'm having this error:

```
connected_app_name: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 114615688-142552 (-705377091)
```

Quesions:

- Does anyone of you have connected app with canvas on your 2gp managed package and can share some thoughts regarding having it on managed package
- Does anyone of you expected any errors with releasing new version of managed package with canvas app inside ?
- Do i have any alternative with having 'iframe' with my external app stored as canvas ?

Comment: How did you end up resolving this? I am wondering whether the 1GP's Connected Apps (we have two in our case) need to have the Canvas App Settings / Lifecycle Class field cleared on the Connected Apps in the 1GP then provide canvasConfig in the ConnectedApp metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If your 1GP connected app has a Lifecycle Class specified, you will need to include that class in your 2GP package as well to avoid an error like the one you posted

Comment: Should the 1GP Connected App have its Lifecycle Class field cleared then would I provide that info in the canvasConfig in the ConnectedApp metadata in the 2GP? My CanvasLifecycle Class is in the 2GP and I prefer not to include it in the 1GP as I only wanted the Connected Apps there.